# Is there anyway to know where a popover was presented from?

Tags: objective-c, ios, popover

I'm writing an iPad app and one of my screens has lots of small buttons that when pressed will display one sentence of text in a popover originating from that button. Currently all popovers are created using the storyboard and I store the popover controller in my `UIViewController` as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]) 
    {
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        self.myPopoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out a good way to deal with rotation.  Right my `didRotate` method looks like so:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (self.myPopoverController) 
    {
        [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: NO];
        [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:??????  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:NO];
    }
}
```

However, I don't know where to present the popovers from given that they could have originated from any of the small buttons on my screen.  Any suggestions?  Remember that these are VERY simple popovers, thus a whole bunch of new code is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be to make another property in your main view controller that keeps a reference to the button pressed. Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *myPopoverController;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *popoverButton;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]) 
    {
        UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        self.myPopoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;

        //The sender in prepareForSegue should be the view used to initiate the segue.
        popoverButton = (UIView *)sender;
    }
}
```

That done, you can modify your rotation code thusly:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (self.myPopoverController) 
    {
        [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: NO];
        [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverButton.frame  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Keeping a reference to the pressed button takes up no more resources that storing a pointer, and keeping the reference weak should avoid retain cycles (after all, your view controller does not own the button, the button's superview owns it).